# Changing The Text Selection Shortcuts on a Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I've recently switched over from a PC to a Mac and I'm wondering if there is any way to edit the text selection/deletion shortcuts on a Mac. I write a lot of code and I've found these shortcuts to be very helpful.

Here is a quick overview of the deletion shortcuts (http://lifehacker.com/5803041/the-mac-os-x-delete-key-it-goes-both-ways); the selection shortcuts on the mac are similar, except that you can use arrow keys instead of delete.

I'd be happy to learn of any method, though I would much prefer it if someone can come up with a way to do it using KeyRemap4MacBook.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "selection shortcuts", aside from "shift-arrow keys", which works the same on both OSes.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure most text editing shortcuts in `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`.

- [TextMate Blog » Key bindings for switchers](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/)
- [hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/KeyBindings/Windows%20Bindings.dict](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/KeyBindings/Windows%20Bindings.dict)